# Run application inside pygame

Tags: python, pygame, window-managers

I'm trying to write a Pygame window manager. I've written a lot of things in pygame before so I can make the program, but I realized I have no idea how to run an application, inside that pygame application. I want to make something similar to gnome 2 but simpler and in pygame. Is there a way to run something inside pygame?

Comment: Because C is gibberish...

Comment: Python can run external program. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/1832058

Comment: Could you explain what *run something inside pygame* means in this context? pygame is just a python library. Also, I don't know how a pygame window manager should work since pygame is based on SDL and SDL needs a running window manager itself (if not run on a framebuffer or something).

Comment: I've found something that will let me run a full screen pygame application from outside of X. I'm curious as to how running an application inside of the window manager works in regular C window managers....  Also? what is the difference (if any) between a window manager and a desktop environment?

Comment: @furas That will open an application but I want the application to run within the pygame application just like in regular window managers

Comment: An instance of pygame currently only handles a single window.  So the main "display" would have to be a pygame window.  I guess that's do-able.  Especially if you start with something simple like a console / terminal emulator windows.

Answer (score 0):

can you do something with the `import` function? Something like this:

```
import pygame, application
```